# Spring boot Header Filtering and Basic Authentication not giving correct response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, basic-authentication

I am doing basic authentication in spring boot . Also i have a filter which does the header filtering and throws error if i dint pass required values in header . Authentication and header filtering are working fine if implemented separately. But if we implement both , i am getting the same response for both the validations ( filter and basic auth ). My guess is as filter response is generated first , it is getting replaced by the authentication response later.

PS: Used ** in code below to tell the issue location . 
Any experts please advice . Thanks

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+2000)
@WebFilter
public class ValidTenantFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        return Constant.TENANT_FILTER_URL_LIST.stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Inside Tenant Checker filter for path {} with  method {} ",request.getServletPath(),request.getMethod());
        if(!this.isValidTenant(request)) {
        **  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Invalid "+ Constant.X_COMPANY_ID+" and/or "+Constant.X_OPERATOR_ID+ " are passed. Please validate the request."); **
        }
        else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidTenant(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Getting company id and operator id from the header , earlier we were using the tenant id 
        String companyId = request.getHeader(Constant.X_COMPANY_ID);
        String operatorId=request.getHeader(Constant.X_OPERATOR_ID);
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(companyId) && StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(companyId) 
            &&  StringUtils.isNotEmpty(operatorId) && StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(operatorId)) {

            Client client = clientRepository.findByIdAndOperatorId(companyId, operatorId);
            //Only active clients request are entertained. // PRODUCT FIX
            if(client!=null && client.getId()!=null && client.isActive()) {
                MDC.put(MDC_CLIENT_ID, client.getId().toString());
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(client.getId().toString());
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And below is the code for the authentication part :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SomeConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPointImpl authEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationClients application;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable();

        //http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/*").requiresSecure();

        http.authorizeRequests()
      //  .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
      //.antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();

        http.headers().defaultsDisabled().cacheControl().and().contentTypeOptions()
        .and().frameOptions().deny().xssProtection().block(false)
        .and().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);

        // Use AuthenticationEntryPoint to authenticate user/password
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        log.info("Importing {} clients:", application.getClients().size());

        application.getClients().forEach(client -> {
            String encrytedPassword = this.passwordEncoder().encode(client.getPassword());
            manager.createUser(User.withUsername(client.getUsername()).password(encrytedPassword).roles(client.getRoles()).build());
            log.info("Imported client {}", client.toString());
        });

        return manager;
    }

}
```

Code for authentication entry point :

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPointImpl extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
                //This is invoked when a user tries to access a secured REST resource without supplying any credentials
                //We should just add a 401 Unauthorized response because there is no 'login page' to redirect to
            **  response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.getOutputStream().println("{\"status\": " + HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED + ", \"message\": \"" + authEx.getMessage() + "\" }");**
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("api-services");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

}
```

Getting below Response in POSTMAN :
1. If i dont pass any credentials in postman i am getting below response

{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}

2. If i dont pass the headers , ideally i should get below response :

{
  "timestamp": 1557753285553,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Invalid X-COMPANY-ID and/or X-OPERATOR-ID are passed. Please validate the request.",
  "path": "/apa/invoices"
}

But instead of this i am getting below error :

3. {
   "status": 401,
   "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
   }

Comment: Your filter is executed AFTER the spring security filter, so adding security will actually disable your filter. You should register your filter BEFORE the Spring Security filter, or make it part of the security filter chain and let it execute as one of the first filters in there.

Comment: can i give like this for the AuthenticationEntryPointImpl as well ? @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+2000)

Comment: tried giving @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE+1999)
public class AuthenticationEntryPointImpl extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint { } . But it dint work

Comment: Filter is not disabled . it is getting executed .

Comment: Changing the order of the authentication entrypoint will NOT affect the filter ordering. I also nowhere said that the filter was disabled, I'm only stating that it is executed after the the spring security chain. Another thing is tha tyou setup `httpBasic` twice. Also Spring Security won't handle your exception from the filter, as that is simply sending a response status. So your content won't ever be JSON but just a status with, optionally, a status text.